# Win32 C++ GUI - take inputed text and show it in another window

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a problem with Win32 C++ GUI. I'm creating a program and as one of the steps, I want to:
1. Let the user type somthing in the textbox,
2. Show it in another box/area,
3. Clear the typed text from the textbox.

It would be something like chat - in one window you type the message and it's shown in the second one.

So far, I have code with 2 windows (not much, I know) and I know that inside WM_COMMAND I should have some code that will take the inputed text and then will pass it to another window (where I want to show messages).

Here is my code (mainly it's Win32 Application default code from CodeBlocks, I just added boxes and button):

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
TCHAR szClassName[ ] = _T("CodeBlocksWindowsApp");
HWND TextBox, SendButton, TextField;


int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                 int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */


    /* The Window structure */
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);
    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;
    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;


    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           _T("Messages"),       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           500,                 /* The programs width */
           370,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );


    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);


    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam,     LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_CREATE:
            TextBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                   "",
                                   WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
                                   10, 300, 390, 20,
                                   hwnd, (HMENU) 1, NULL, NULL);
            SendButton = CreateWindow("BUTTON",
                         "Send",
                          WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
                         410, 300, 65, 20,
                         hwnd, (HMENU) 2, NULL, NULL);
            TextField = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                                     "",
                                     WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | ES_READONLY,
                                     10, 90, 465, 200,
                                     hwnd, (HMENU) 3, NULL, NULL);
            break;
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 1: // when button is clicked, this will happen:
                // what code should go here??
                break;
            }
        break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;
        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

My question is: what functions should I use (and how) to take the users input and display it in another window.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Your `#if` block at the top isn't necessary. In C, it is legal to echo the same `#define` statement multiple times so long as the replacement text is the same, so if `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are both defined to be replaced with the empty string, just saying `#define UNICODE` and `#define _UNICODE` will suffice. I am not familiar with any header file that predefines these macros, especially if nothing is included first =P

Comment: @andlabs, this is just what default Win32 Application in CodeBlocks gave me, I'll get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unintuitive.

You want to be able to get the window text for the two edit controls. The text currently entered into an edit control is the window text. Those use the generic `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` and `WM_GETTEXT` messages. Likewise, `WM_SETTEXT` sets the window text.

Now here's where it gets a little confusing: there *is* a way to insert text at a given position in an edit (or even a rich edit) control. But there's no `EM_INSERTTEXT` or `EM_REPLACETEXT` or whatever. There *is*, however, an `EM_REPLACESEL`, which replaces the *current selection* with new text.

The [documentation for `EM_REPLACESEL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761633%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says

> If there is no selection, the replacement text is inserted at the caret.

So how do you move the caret? Well, going back to our metaphor of selections, [the documentation for `EM_GETSEL`, the message to find out which text is currently selected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761598%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), says

> If there is no selection, the starting and ending values are both the position of the caret.

So to add text, you have to

1. Move the selection so that it both starts and ends at the position you want to add to. [If you want to add text to the end, use values of -1 for both.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. Use `EM_REPLACESEL` to add the text.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with your code that processes the WM_COMMAND message.

First, you use case 1 to detect when the button is clicked, however the control id of the button is 2 and not 1.

Second, you don't check to see what kind of notification message the button is sending. Buttons can (and do) use WM_COMMAND messages to notify your program of things other than clicks, so if you want to do something only when the button is checked you have to make sure that the WM_COMMAND message is for a BN_CLICKED notification (by checking the high word of the wParam parameter).

You could have switch statements nested three deep (with a switch to identify the message, and a switch inside that to identify the control, and then a switch inside that to identify the notification code), but if I were you I would put the code for processing messages from the button in a separate function and call that function in your WM_COMMAND processing code. I'm thinking of something like this.

```
        case WM_COMMAND:
            switch(LOWORD(wParam))
            {
                case 2: // when button is clicked, this will happen:
                ProcessButtonMessage(HIWORD(wParam)); //Pass the notification code to the processing function.
                break;
            }
        break;
```

The processing function could look something like this

```
static void ProcessButtonMessage(WORD wNotification)
{
    switch(wNotification)
    {
    case BN_CLICKED:
       //Add code to process button click here
       break;
    }
}
```

Now as far as what functions to use to transfer the text. You would get the text the user has entered by sending a WM_GETTEXT message to the text box receiving the user input, and transfer it to the other text box using EM_REPLACESEL as suggested by the previous answer, and you can send the WM_SETTEXT message (with an empty string) to first text box to erase the text the user has entered.